# Paypal Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution gives pending payment status in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, paypal, paypal-payments-pro

We have set Website Payments Pro Hosted paypal in website. But after order, it shows as pending payment in admin and it says total due. But i noticed the payment is made in paypal. After some searching i found it might be the cause of ipn. So i have set magento ipn url in paypal. But still the issue is not fixed.

Now i have removed the ipn. Dont know what is the issue. I have tried checking with sandbox. But everytime i click place order it shows, *your transaction cant be processed, please pay with another card*.

I have checked the paypal log. But the *[ACK] => Success* is the status. When i checked the order detail page in magento admin, I can see the paypal last transaction id and other details are not showing: http://prntscr.com/6x5jay

Could anyone assist me in fixing this. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enable the log for this and check what is showing in the error log while making paypal. May be you will get something from the paypal default magento error log. Please post the output so that i can look more into this.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the following links. Hope this will help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252427/magento-1-7-0-2-pending-payment-status-after-successful-payment-in-paypal

http://www.develodesign.co.uk/blog/item/129-paypal-hosted-payments-pro-fix-for-magento

Comment: In app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/HostedPro.php
i can see 
public function getNotifyUrl($storeId = null)
{
    return $this->_getUrl('paypal/ipn', $storeId, false);
}

wil it work if i give hard magento payapl ipn url here?

Answer (score 1):

Atlast fixed... The issue is with the mail id of paypal.
how i resolved: https://inchoo.net/magento/debugging-paypal-ipn-in-magento/